# How can I show Stickers from Document directory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, msstickerview, mssticker

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            var x : Int = 0
            for item in self.arrGifs
            {
                let gif : GIF = item as! GIF
                let gifName = URL(string: gif.gifImage)?.lastPathComponent
                // let ur
                let pathUrl = URL.urlInDocumentsDirectory(with: "\(gifName!)").path

                print("image path is =====>", pathUrl)



                //RawImages.xcassets


                // if let url =  Bundle.main.url(forResource:"3", withExtension: "gif")
               //  {
                    print("url is ------>>>> ",url)
                    do
                    {
                        let sticker = try
                      //     MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url,localizedDescription: "")
                            MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: URL(string:pathUrl)!,localizedDescription: "")



                        self.arrSticker.append(sticker)
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
               //  }
            }
            self.createStickerBrowser()
    }
```

Well for the above " MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url,localizedDescription: "")" I can get stickers which are saved in Bundle. But If I give path of document directry, no sticker are shown.
I am downloading the imges from api, saving in my sqlite(image name) and images in document directry so that user can view it Offline. I find no solutions . Need help what is wrong and how to do it right.
Thank you.

```
     file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8FF754B-F012-4B75-AA2E-9FA71846E6AB/Migos%20Lingo.app/PlugIns/MigosLingo.appex/3.gif === this from Bundle and I can view as Sticker

    /var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DE11FB0E-89F9-4A65-917E-B4FEB8CA5470/Documents/111111-1508763742.gif   ===> Document directry and I cannot view as Stickers
```

Comment: Yes.

    /var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/DE11FB0E-89F9-4A65-917E-B4FEB8CA5470/Documents/111111-1508763742.gif
----111111-1508763742.gif--- is my image name.

Comment: how are you saving image after download gif file from server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
```

After this make url because **MSSticker** create sticker with url path.Don't forget to append your image name with document path. after getting image path just do this.

```
let pathurl =  URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath!)
```

now you can creat sticker.

```
MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: pathurl, localizedDescription: "hello world")
```