# Unable to display Stickers from Documents directory in iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory, imessage-extension, ios-stickers

In my app users are able to create images and then use them as stickers in iMessages.

My problem is that I can't display created images that are stored in the Documents Directory.

My issue is very similar to this question - [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406180/how-can-i-show-stickers-from-document-directory-in-swift) but in my case the solution stated there didn't help.

Here's my code for fetching images:

```
 func getImages(finished: () -> Void) {
    imageData.removeAll()
    let imageNames = keyboardUserDefaults!.stringArray(forKey: "Created stickers")
    for imageName in imageNames! {
        //  let imagePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let filePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
        // imageData.append(imagePath + "/" + imageName)
        imageData.append(filePath)
    }

    print("Image Data - ", imageData)

    finished()
}
```

And here is how I apply it to StickerView:

```
 func configure(usingImageName imagePath: String) {
        let urlToImage = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
        do {
            let description = NSLocalizedString("", comment: "")
            let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: urlToImage, localizedDescription: description)

            print("Sicker is here - ", sticker)

            stickerView.sticker = sticker
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create sticker: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting a blank view with no stickers.

Print inside cell shows:

```
Sicker is here -  <MSSticker-<0x280393640> imageFileURL file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/32AF9E44-F2F1-4FD1-80B5-E8E4B6C6E338/Documents/F54067B8-18DA-4737-8ED3-B716E368AF6E.png localizedDescription >
```

Images are showing when I set them from my folder inside Xcode project using `Bundle.main.path`, but not from the Documents Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found source of my problem:

Application Extensions can't access default Documents Directory folder.

Solution:

Use App Groups and make path for image when saving and retrieving it like this:

```
let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "YOUR_APP_GROUP_NAME")?.appendingPathComponent("image.png")
```

After that you can easily access your images in Application Extensions.

Hope this helps someone in future!